# Is there a way to fix gimp on OSX to solve the xwindows focus issue?

Tags: macos, gimp

When running GIMP on OS X you have to click on the toolbar window once, then click again to select a tool because the window was not in focus.

And you have to do this over and over again because when you click back to the drawing window or layers window each has its own focus.  Anyway to make this more usable on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that 2.7.3 and later have a Single-Window mode that may solve your issue. I'm not sure how you have GIMP installed on OS X, but you can probably get 2.7.3+ [using MacPorts](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111117032604297).

Comment: can't thank you enough.  you just changed my life forever.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get 2.7.3 to work, I also found that in GIMP 2.6.11 there is an option in
X11 preferences in the "windows" section for "click-through inactive windows". digitxp's solution is better but 2.7.3 crashes for me on Lion any time I try and use the text tool.